# How can I add touch listener for each element of an recyclerview item.

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch-event

My case : 
 - I have a RecyclerView with complex item (many ImageView, texts .. )
 - I use 4 ImageView as 4 buttons (Like, Comment, Share, Dislike)
 - I want to use TouchListener for each button, because I want to control animation, also click event. ( I know how to use ClickListener for each item so please focus on TouchEvent ) Example : Facebook Comment button of each Story on NewsFeed, when you touch onto the button, animation scale icon. Click event just go on after release the button.

Problem is : I just can get Parent View of each Item (ex : LinearLayout contain other components of each item) by using recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x,y).

So how to know which button was clicked like when we use clickListener :
- button1.setClickListener(this);
- button2.setClickListener(this); (on View Holder)
And after that catch event in Activity or Fragment :
- switch(view.getId()) {
case R.id.button1: .. do something; break;
case R.id.button2: .. do something; break;
....
I google this problem all day but all sample and answer just use ClickListener like I said above.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

inside recyclerview adapter use like this

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapterA.ViewHolder_a holder, final int position) {
      holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                            }
                        });
```

Comment: you want listener to react back to your activity or fragment right?

Comment: That's not  problem. I want to catch touch event of each button on each item of recyclerView. Ex: I touch button1, catch touchevent (move up, down) or gestureListener (onDown, onSingleTabUp, onLongPress ... )

Answer (score 0):

You get parent view by by

```
View parent = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x,y);
```

Now you can easily get its corresponding views e.g.

```
Button button = (Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Hope you understand!!!

Comment: @bpAFee, but if that, do you know which button I just touched?

Comment: that would be get from your parent view that you get by recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x,y);

Comment: recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x,y) -> this method return bound view, parent view of whole item not exact child item